# Footer stays at the bottom in one page and jumps to the middle of another page

Tags: html, css, less

I am creating a footer for my Angular application. This is the code for my footer:

```
// HTML
<footer class="footer">
    //  code for footer
</footer>

// LESS
.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.content {
    min-height: 500px;
}

// Application's layout:
<app-header1></app-header1>
    <div class="container content">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

This works fine in my homepage. However, when I navigate to a different page, the footer jumps to the middle of the page and stays there when I scroll the page. I notice that if I remove `bottom: 0;`, the footer then goes to bottom. However, when I navigate back to homepage (with `bottom: 0;`), the footer does not stay in the bottom anymore. It kind of floats in the middle between homepage's content and bottom.

PAGES with `bottom: 0;`
[image]

[image]

PAGES with NO `bottom: 0;`
[image]

[image]

PAGE with `position: fixed;`
[image]

Comment: You would probably find more desirable results using `position: fixed;` instead of absolute :) try that

Comment: i suggest you use flexbox to solve this and not position https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/

Comment: I tried `position: fixed;` but I still don't get my desired result. Now footer does stays in the bottom of the page, but it is on top of the content as I scroll.

Comment: there might be 2 problems. 1: your footer is not the last element on the page 2: your are using position property for those form container.  Try not using position property for the elements and check

Comment: @Kuru Hi please see my app's layout I just added. I believe I have my footer component in right position. I also removed all position property (1 or 2) and only keep position for footer but I still have same issue.

Comment: @Dirk I tried your suggestion, but I got the exact behavior I was getting in which my footer stays in the bottom in homepage and jumps to middle of another longer page.

Comment: I don't know if this is an optimal or right way to deal with footer, but I am adding `min-height: 500px` to the `.content` class to force footer to stay in bottom. Any comments about this?

Answer (score 0):

well, I thinks that you should change `footer` to a div and put your footer under all your block elements above

HTML

```
<div class="footer">
        //  code for footer
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.footer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: fit-content;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: `<div>` and `<footer>` are both block elements by default, so changing the HTML element serves no purpose. It may be better to keep it as a `<footer>` element since it's more descriptive.

Comment: Oh, if not that, I think he not put the footer in the right position, maybe he not put it under all block element above on the html

Comment: To answer your questions, I posted my app's layout above. I believe I have put footer component in the right order.